# *ngIf window.location.href.indexOf is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to show one element only if location is right, if not, it shoudn't be shown.

This is not working:

```
<div *ngIf="!accessTrue() && window.location.href.indexOf('something')" > -1)>
    CODE
</div>
```

Comment: That wasn't the case here. But thanks :)

Comment: try to set a boolean flag `true/false` in component only, don't call function in `*ngIf`

Comment: Please post code

Comment: @eric.dummy: I've posted as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot access the `window` object inside the template.
But you can define a getter in your component :

```
get hasSomething(){
    return window.location.href.indexOf('something') > -1
}
```

then :

```
<div *ngIf="!accessTrue() && hasSomething">
    CODE
</div>
```

Note that it might be cleaner to use an `ActivatedRoute` if your parameter is accessible through it.

Comment: Thanks, how would you use it with ActivatedRoute?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML :

```
 <div *ngIf="hasAccess"> CODE </div>
```

In angular Component :

```
constructor(){
        this.hasAccess = window.location.href.indexOf('something') > -1 && !this.accessTrue();
}
```